# amp-carousel heights attribute with fixed layout?

Tags: css, amp-html

```
<amp-carousel 
    layout="fixed-height" 
    height="426" 
    type="carousel" 
    heights="(min-width:957px) 426px, 376px">

       <amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x210/ccc/aaa" height="210" 
           width="400"
           sizes="(min-width: 957px) 400px, 210px">
       </amp-img>

</amp-carousel>
```

The code below works as intended i.e. carousel height changes with screen size but error pops up

`The attribute 'heights' in tag 'amp-carousel' is disallowed by specified layout 'FIXED_HEIGHT'.`

without the fixed-height layout, horizontal scroll is not working as intended.

I tried reducing duplicate code as written in [this page](https://www.ampproject.org/stories/#web-stories-carousel) to showcase stories.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "heights" attribute with layout="fixed-height", read it here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/common_attributes#heights

So basically if you want to have responsive height, go with layout="responsive" and set heights attribute. Otherwise if you are going with layout="fixed-height" you have to duplicate the code with different "media" attribute(as seen in the link you have shared). Which works as, if the media condition is satisfied than only that particular tag will come into play otherwise that will be display none.

Comment: You are right, `heights` attribute can only be used with AMP custom elements that allow `responsive` layout. But I would also like to point out that `responsive` layout is not supported for `amp-carousel` with `type="carousel"`, and only for `type="slides"`